# Initialize numpy array of size N with arrays of size M

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking to create a numpy array that looks something like this

```
N=4
M=3
my_array = np.zeros(...) # or np.full, np.ones...
print(my_array)
>>> [[0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0.] [0. 0. 0.]] # Array of 4 arrays with 3 elements
```

The elements don't need to be zero I am just trying to initialize an array in this structure. I do not want to use lists or tuples.

I've tried something like this

```
N=4
M=3
kg_neurons1 = np.full(shape=4,fill_value=np.zeros(M))
```

But this raises `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (4,)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `np.zeros((N,M))`?

Comment: @Ftagliacarne Ah, I have no idea why I didn't think of that, yes that works thank you!

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a NumPy array with a specific shape, you can use the `np.zeros` function and pass the desired shape as a tuple. In your case, you want an array with 4 rows and 3 columns, so you can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 4
M = 3
my_array = np.zeros((N, M))

print(my_array)
```

This will produce the output:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

This creates a NumPy array with 4 rows and 3 columns, initialized with zeros.